# Coluna index utilizando dados do meu arquivo csv

Tags: python, csv, índices

Boa noite a todos!

Abri um arquivo csv no python utilizando o seguinte comando:

```
caminhoarquivo = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\teste.csv'

basedados = pd.read_csv(caminhoarquivo,sep=';',decimal=',', encoding='latin-1')
```

Porém na primeira linha (rótulo do csv) ele insere "index" e considera nesta coluna os dados da primeira coluna do meu csv, deixando a última coluna do csv sem informações.
Gostaria que alguém me ajudasse a inserir nessa coluna "index", números ao invés de utilizar dados do meu arquivo. Para assim não deslocar o rótulo, deixando a ultima coluna sem informações.

Exemplo do arquivo:

```
Ponto de Medição|      Data          |Hora|Consumo|Status
  User1         |   30/11/2018       | 24 |  23,5 |  OK 
  User1         |   30/11/2018       |  1 |  14,8 |  OK
  User1         |   30/11/2018       |  2 |  48,6 |  OK
  User1         |   30/11/2018       |  3 |  92,3 |  OK
  User1         |   30/11/2018       |  4 |  76,2 |  OK
```

Após abrir no Python:

```
  Index         |  Ponto de Medição|  Data|   Hora|Consumo|Status
  User1         |   30/11/2018       | 24 |  23,5 |  OK   |
  User1         |   30/11/2018       |  1 |  14,8 |  OK   |
  User1         |   30/11/2018       |  2 |  48,6 |  OK   |
  User1         |   30/11/2018       |  3 |  92,3 |  OK   |
  User1         |   30/11/2018       |  4 |  76,2 |  OK   |
```

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: E como esta seu arquivo *CSV* ? Teria como colocar uma parte ou um exemplo de como esta ?

Comment: Inseri uma parte do arquivo csv. Quando abro ele no Python ele desloca a primeira linha e insere "index" fazendo com que 'User1" esteja na coluna rotulada como "index". Sendo assim a coluna "status" fica vazia.

Comment: **Felipe**, seria importante colocar o texto ao invés de imagem, devido a restrições eu não consigo ver a imagem.

Comment: Inseri um exemplo.

Comment: Testei aqui e pra mim esta normal, seu código é somente esse que colocou aqui ou tem mais código?